# How to prove NegativeBinomial(r,p) converges to Gamma(r,1) as p->0

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

Let $X\sim NegBin(r,p)$ and $Y\sim Gamma(r,1)$.

How can I prove that $pX \overset{dist}\to Y$ as $p\to 0$.

Is this statement the same as $X\overset{dist}\to Gamma(r,1/p)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Read how a binomial distribution converges to the Poisson and apply the same techniques. The Gamma distribution is the waiting time for the $r$-th arrival in a Poisson process: the negative binomial distribution is the waiting time for the occurrence of the $r$-th success of an event of probability $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my handwritten answer:
(typo: pdf)
[image: This only provides a rough idea]

This is my typed answer:

$P_{NB}(X)= \left ( _{k}^{k+r-1}\textrm{} \right )(1-p)^{r}p^{k}$

$=\frac{(k+r-1)!}{k!(r-1)!}(1-p)^{\frac{1}{p}*rp}p^{k}$

$=\frac{(k+r-1)(k+r-2)...(k+1)}{(r-1)!}[(1-p)^{\frac{1}{p}}]^{rp}p^{k}$

$\approx \frac{k^{r-1}}{\Gamma (r)}e^{-rp}p^{k}$

The tricks are:

1.You have to use (1-p)^(1/p) is converged to e when p is small.

2.Gamma function(k) = (k+1)!

3.(r+x choose r ) converages to (r+x)(r+x-1)(r+x-2)...r / r!

You will easily derive the formula with all the three above plugged in

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. Will try to write it up rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question, was asked and answered years ago, but I'm going to derive $Gamma(t;k,\lambda)$ from a limit of $NegBin(r;k,p)$ in a more general way for posterity's sake. Here $r$ denotes the failures before obtaining $k$ successes.

Starting from $NegBin(r;k,p) = {{r+k+1} \choose {k-1}}p^k(1-p)^{r}$, we set $p = \lambda/n$ and $r = tn$. Why $r = tn$? Because the number of failures goes to $\infty$. You can think of $n = 1/\delta t$ ($\delta t$ is the time per Bernoulli trial), so that $t$ is linearly proportional to the number of failures (which occur with a probability approaching 1).

This yields: ${{nt+k+1} \choose {k-1}}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{nt}$

Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ yields:

$\frac{t^{k-1}\lambda^k}{(k-1)!}\lambda^k e^{-\lambda t}\delta t = Gamma(t;k,\lambda)\delta t$.